# Does PHP proc_nice leave Apache threads at new priority setting?

Tags: php, apache, apache2, nice, renice

When executing proc_nice(), is it actually nice'ing Apache's thread?

If so, and if the current user (non-super user) can't renice to its original priority is killing the Apache thread appropriate (apache_child_terminate) on an Apache 2.0x server?

The issue is that I am trying to limit the impact of an app that allows the user to run Ad-Hack queries.  The Queries can be massive and the resultant transform on the data requires a lot of Memory and CPU.

I've already re-written the process to be more stream based - helping with the memory consumption, but I would also like the process to run a lower priority.  However I can't leave the Apache thread in low priority as we have a lot of high-priority web services running on this same box.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that kind of situation, a solution if often to not do that kind of heavy work within the Apache processes, but either :

- run an external PHP process, using something like [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), for instance -- this is if you must work in synchronous mode (ie, if you cannot execute the task a couple of minutes later)
- push the task to a FIFO system, and immediatly return a message to the user saying "your task will be processed soon"

  - and have some other process *(launched via a crontab every minute, for instance)* check that FIFO queue
  - and do the processing it there is something in the queue
  - That process, itself, can run in low priority mode.

As often as possible, especially if the heavy calculations take some time, I would go for the second solution :

- It allows users to get some feedback immediatly : "the server has received your request, and will process it soon"
- It doesn't keep Apaches's processes "working" for long : the heavy stuff is done by other processes
- If, one day, you need such an amount of processing power that one server is not enough anymore, this kind of system will be easier to scale : just add a second server that'll pick from the same FIFO queue
- If your server is really too loaded, you can stop processing from the queue, at least for some time, so the load can get better -- for instance, this can be usefull if your critical web-services are used a lot in a specific time-frame.

Another *(nice-looking, but I haven't tried it yet)* solution would be to use some kind of tool like, for instance, [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) :

> Gearman provides a generic application
>   framework to farm out work to other
>   machines or processes that are better
>   suited to do the work. 
> It allows you
>   to do work in parallel, to load
>   balance processing, and to call
>   functions between languages. 
> It can be
>   used in a variety of applications,
>   from high-availability web sites to
>   the transport of database replication
>   events. 
> In other words, it is the
>   nervous system for how distributed
>   processing communicates.

Comment: Thanks for the generous detail.  I have already split this system out into a request/queue system as you described (some queries can take hours to finish), though it is a web-service that does the work (and therefor Apache is still involved).  I discussed this with a coworker who also suggested forking off a CLI worker to do the the actual work which can then be "niced".  I'll take a look at Gearman, but in the meantime I will consider changing to a CLI worker.

Comment: YOu're welcome :-) ;; If your tasks are taking that long, a CLI application, separate from Apache, seems to really be required : else, you'll end with no available Apache process to serve pages, one day or another... Still, Have fun !